# MySQL is not connecting over SSL in java REST applications

Tags: java, mysql, ssl

I generated Keystore in Java home path. Set up the Connector in tomcat server.xml for the port 8443.

MySQL is not getting connected.

Added the following logic in java mysql connection class

```
   String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxxx"
                "?verifyServerCertificate=false"+
                "&useSSL=true"+
                "&requireSSL=true";

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pwd");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your key store config have some problem. Please check this [link](http://albertolarripa.com/2012/06/02/how-to-enable-data-encryption-ssl-for-a-jdbc-driver/). Also, please attach error report.

Comment: have_ssl is still disabled. ssl keys are not displaying in the commmand show variables like "%ssl";                                 I followed http://albertolarripa.com/2012/05/28/encrypted-mysql-connection/

Comment: I followed all the instructions to set up ssl connection in mysql using the http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/have_ssl/.  Still ssl_cipher is not displaying any values

Comment: @SindhuShashidhar i will try and tough u soon